# svelte подружить с backend

Tags: svelte

Я немного нуб, и не могу найти правильный туториал.

Если у меня к примеру, сервер на php (чисто для api), как мне прикручивать к нему svelte + еще чтоб оно на одном домене Было?

И еще чтоб я еще мог открывать какую-то ссылку кроме как `/`

Направьте просто на туториал. Большое Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

[Маршруты сервера](https://ru.sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Marshruty_servera)

Серверные маршруты — это модули, написанные в файлах .js, которые экспортируют функции, соответствующие HTTP методам. Каждая функция получает в качестве аргументов объекты HTTP request и response, а также функцию next. Это полезно для создания JSON API. Например, вот как бы вы могли бы создать эндпоинт для обслуживания страницы блога:

```
// routes/blog/[slug].json.js
import db from './_database.js'; // нижнее подчёркивание, говорит Sapper, что это не маршрут

export async function get(req, res, next) {
    // у нас есть доступ к параметру `slug`, потому что
    // файл называется [slug].json.js
    const { slug } = req.params;

    const article = await db.get(slug);

    if (article !== null) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(article));
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```